# Input boxes persisting over to next page ICS

Tags: html, css, iframe, cordova

**Background:**

I'm developing a PG application for some clients. I've got an online page (which I don't have any control on) which is a login page, having two text boxes and a button. I load that page inside an iframe, so that the user puts in his/her id & password. From there on, the user is re-directed to some other page within the same iframe.

**Problem:**

When the user goes to the next page, the highlights (an outline kinda thing) appears wherever the text boxes were appearing previously in the login page.This happens whenever I tap on the areas where the inputs were present in the previous page. Here's a photo for reference. ***Please note that this happens only in Android ICS.***

[image]

**Code:**

The iframe tag has the following styles added to it.

```
iframe {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    padding: 0;
    height: 89%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

    iframe.changed {
        margin-top: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

The redirection happens this way :

```
//after login
document.getElementById("app-frame").contentWindow.location.replace(url);
```

Anything Im missing here? Any idea why these text boxes persist even after the parent page is gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by myself. A very weird fix indeed. I loaded "about:blank" and after 100 ms, I loaded the needed url. This way, it worked. A reflow was triggered, as expected & the artifacts of the previous page were gone. This is the code :

```
var frame = document.getElementById("app-frame");
frame.contentWindow.location.replace("about:blank");
setTimeout(function () {
   frame.contentWindow.location.replace(url);
}, 100);
```